# SQL Server agent job step - if exists not evaluating

Tags: sql-server, exists

I have set up a job in SQL Server 2016 to monitor a table and notifiy via email if certain data exists.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM NPS_Logging.dbo.accounting_data WHERE "NP_Policy_Name" LIKE 'VPN%' AND "timestamp" > DATEADD(day,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
BEGIN
 send email (won't bother showing full commands as they work as mentioned below)
END
```

When I tested the job I didn't get an email.

I thought that the `if exists` wasn't evaluating (I know it should at the moment) so I manually ran the `SELECT 1...` query and it returned 1.

I then thought that the send email was broken so I placed it outside the begin/end and tested.

```
if exists (SELECT 1 ...
BEGIN
END
send email
```

And it worked, I got an email.

Can anyone see where I may have gone wrong?

Comment: Obviously that the `IF` condition returns `FALSE`. Check the `exists` query

Comment: I have manually run the select query in the `if exists` statement and it returns a 1 for each record it finds (at the moment there are six such records).

Comment: are you running it under the same security context as the `SQL Server Agent` ?

Comment: I've set the owner of the job the same as the owner of the database in question, which is the account I am using to manualy run the exists query.  Woldn't I ge an error if it couldn't read the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes:

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM NPS_Logging.dbo.accounting_data WHERE NP_Policy_Name LIKE 'VPN%' AND timestamp > DATEADD(day,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
BEGIN
 send email (won't bother showing full commands as they work as mentioned below)
END

Personally, when I do this sort of thing I like to retrieve the record count instead of using IF EXISTS...I often use the record in the body or subject of the email.